# Getting GoogleDrive user information

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

How can I get current user's details such as email, name, etc?
I tried using `About about = service.About.Get().Fetch();`
But it only gave me user's display name.
Is there another function that can give more details?

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of the .NET client library, please consider to upgrade to http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/. Regrading your actual question I'm pretty sure that you need to use another API to get more information, just because Drive shouldn't provide that information. Maybe G+ or OAuth2? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the email, **if** the user have allowed the account you are logged in using the [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) from the Google API.

With the [About](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about) portion of the api you can get the `permissionId` of the user.

The `list` command of Permissions requires a fileId that the authenticated user have access to (ex. the root folder) to work

After you get the results, you can filter the objects with `type=user` and `id=PERMISSION_ID_FROM_ABOUT` and you can have the email (`emailAddress`) if the user share the information on Google+ (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850066/1562589) about email visibility).